# Accessing protected event of TWinControl

Tags: delphi, rtti

imagine, you want to assign your own event procedure:

```
procedure TSuperObject.DoSomething(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
ShowMessage('Yes, I am doing');
end;
```

to any TWinControl on the form. Normally if you have Panel1 (TPanel) on the form, you can do it easy:

```
Panel1.OnMouseDown:=SuperObject1.DoSomething;
```

But if you want to do it universally, how can it be accomplished? You can not access protected members of TWincontrol, so intuitive answer:

```
AnyWinControl.OnMouseDown:=SuperObject1.DoSomething;
```

simply does not work.

Can it be done by RTTI? How?

Thanx

Comment: You can create a class (inherited from TControls) publishing the protected Events and assign the events by casting to this class. e.g. `THack(MyClass).OnMouseDown := ...` to do so your class will have to be a descendant of TControl.

Comment: @bummi:  the same for you... :-)

Comment: I guess this is a dupe many times over: http://www.google.com/m?q=delphi+protected+hack+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Be aware there already is a Delphi [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/) that parses and writes [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need RTTI.

Any code has implicit access to the protected members of any class declared **in the same unit**. You can take advantage of this by declaring a new `TWinControl` descendant in the unit that needs access to that class's members. The declaration is very simple:

```
type
  TProtectedWinControl = class(TWinControl);
```

Then type-cast any other `TWinControl` descendant to that new type, and you'll have access to any of its protected fields, properties, and methods. Protected members of `TWinControl` are automatically protected members of `TProtectedWinControl` (through inheritance), so the current unit has access to them.

```
TProtectedWinControl(AnyWinControl).OnMouseDown := SuperObject1.DoSomething;
```

Note that this applies to *protected* members, but not ***strict*** protected members.

Comment: I think you might be a genius... ;-)