# How to detect whether a TWinControl has a FONT property?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to change the FONT property of controls collected via the `Controls` property of a container control:

```
for i := 0 to ContainerControl.ControlCount - 1 do
begin  
  ContainerControl.Controls[i].Font.Size := 8;  // error  
end;
```

For this, I would need to typecast `ContainerControl.Controls[i]` to a class of TWinControl having a FONT property. Is there such a class? Or how can I detect whether a specific TWinControl has a FONT property? Or how cany I typecast a specific TWincontrol to the type of a specific other TWinControl?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you have a windowed control with a lot of child controls, you can change the font of all children by simply changing the font of the parent. This works by default, since `ParentFont` is `True` by default. Otherwise, if you know you only have a small number of possible classes, you can do a plain boring `if Controls[i] is TEdit then TEdit(Controls[i]).Font.Name := 'Comic Sans MS' else if Controls[i] is TButton then...`

Comment: For specific reasons which are too complex to explain here, I cannot use `ParentFont`.

Comment: You are mistaken. You can use ParentFont

Comment: For specific reasons which are too complex to explain here, I cannot use ParentFont IN MY SPECIFIC CASE. For example, to restrict the controls to specific types to specific font changes.

Comment: if Assigned(GetPropInfo(ContainerControl.Controls[i], 'font')) then

Comment: Keep in mind that some controls may have more than 1 font property. Of course there's the main `Font` as noted, but may also have different elements that require separate font properties. For example, the `TChromeTabs` third-party control has numerous ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Every** TControl has a Font property, it's just protected. So you can use [the usual cast trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067430/accessing-protected-event-of-twincontrol):

```
type
  TControlAccess = class(TControl);

TControlAccess(MyControl).Font.Size := 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

All visual controls have a `Font` property, but it is `protected` at the `TControl` layer, and not all derived controls promote it to `published`.  If you are interested in only controls that have a *published* `Font` than you have to use RTTI to test them, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

var
  Ctrl: TControl;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ContainerControl.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin  
    Ctrl := ContainerControl.Controls[i];
    if IsPublishedProp(Ctrl, 'Font') then
      TFont(GetObjectProp(Ctrl, 'Font', TFont)).Size := 8;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

var
  Ctrl: TControl;
  Prop: PPropInfo;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ContainerControl.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin  
    Ctrl := ContainerControl.Controls[i];
    Prop := GetPropInfo(Ctrl, 'Font', [tkClass]);
    if Prop <> nil then
      TFont(GetObjectProp(Ctrl, Prop, TFont)).Size := 8;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, in Delphi 2010 and later only:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Rtti;

var
  Ctrl: TControl;
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to ContainerControl.ControlCount - 1 do
    begin  
      Ctrl := ContainerControl.Controls[i];
      Prop := Ctx.GetType(Ctrl.ClassType).GetProperty('Font');
      if (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility = TMemberVisibility.mvPublished) then
        TFont(Prop.GetValue(Ctrl).AsObject).Size := 8;
    end;
  finally
    Ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```